# Eclipse doesn't recognize c++ files

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, cocos2d-x

I created a cocos2d-x v3 project. But when I opened Eclipse, the Classes folder wasn't recognizing the files inside it. So I deleted it, and created a sym link of the Classes folder in the home directory of the project to the android.proj folder. But now, my app is not running on Android and I'm getting error in all C++ classes saying "syntax error".

I did the sym link like this:

```
ln -s /Users/filipeferminiano/documents/astori/hero_rush/Classes Classes
```

Comment: Well, why do you need to symlink Classes? Resources maybe, but the way Cocos2d-x projects are setup is that they all share a classes directory. You are running v3 I'd go through this: http://cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_Start_A_New_Cocos2D-X_Game

Comment: ok, but I was trying to code the c++ classes in eclipse, which was impossible. Because classes folder didn't opened the classes files in Eclipse

Comment: Then your setup is wrong. Read this: http://cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_Build_an_Android_Project_with_Eclipse

Comment: Check out Step 2 in tutorial here: http://patidarvikas.blogspot.in/2014/04/run-cocos2dx-android-project-on-windows.html